# Fax "from" and "callerId" parameters missing from RingCentral fax API

Tags: api, post, fax, ringcentral, caller-id

I've been trying to send fax using RingCentral API but there is no way to specify the `From` fax phone number to send the fax. It is only sending the fax using company fax number. I am not able to find the option to use fax from number. I am using the following end point for sending fax:

https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/:accountId/extension/:extensionId/fax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the RingCentral system, the `From` (or sending) fax number is the fax caller ID value. You can update this for your extension to use with your faxes, but the value is not available in the send fax API itself. To change this on a per send basis, you can update the caller ID value before each fax request.

You can update the Fax Caller ID using two approaches:

1. via API or
2. using the Online Account Portal (https://service.ringcentral.com), both of which are described below.

Both are described below. Let me know if this works for you.

**1) Updating the Fax Caller ID**

To update the fax caller ID, call the `PUT extension/caller-id` endpoint and update the `callerId` for the `FaxNumber` feature using the phone number ID of the number you are interested in using. You can get a list of this by calling the `extension/phone-number` shown in the next section.

```
PUT /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/caller-id
Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "byFeature": [
    {
      "feature": "FaxNumber",
      "callerId": {
        "phoneInfo": {
          "id": 33333333
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

See the API Reference for more: https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefUpdateCallerId

**1.1) Listing Your Available Caller ID Numbers**

To get a list a list of numbers you can use, call the `GET extension/phone-number` endpoint:

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/phone-number
Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}
```

In your JSON response, you will have a list of phone numbers in the `records` property. Numbers that you can use will have the following property values:

- `features` property will have the `CallerId` value
- `type` property will be set to `VoiceFax` or `FaxOnly`

The following is the excerpt of a JSON response showing one number. You should have more numbers and a `paging` object.

```
{
  "uri":"https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/phone-number?page=1&perPage=100",
  "records":[
    {
      "id":33333333,
      "phoneNumber":"+16505550100",
      "paymentType":"Local",
      "location":"Belmont, CA",
      "type":"VoiceFax",
      "usageType":"DirectNumber",
      "status":"Normal",
      "country":{
        "uri":"https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/country/1",
        "id":"1",
        "name":"United States"
      },
      "features":[
        "SmsSender",
        "CallerId",
        "MmsSender"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

See the API Reference for more: https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefUserPhoneNumbers.html

**1.2) Reading The Fax Caller ID Value**

RingCentral supports multiple caller ID values. To read the value for your extension make the following API call to the `extension/caller-id` endpoint:

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/caller-id
Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}
```

You will receive a response like the following with an array of caller ID values in the `byFeature` property. Look for the feature with the `feature` property set to `FaxNumber`. I only show the `FaxNumber` feature caller ID below, but the array includes the following features: `CallFlip`, `FaxNumber`, `RingMe`, `RingOut`, `MobileApp`, `Alternate`.

```
{
  "uri":"https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/caller-id",
  "byFeature":[
    {
      "feature":"FaxNumber",
      "callerId":{
        "type":"PhoneNumber",
        "phoneInfo":{
          "uri":"https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/phone-number/33333333",
          "id":"33333333",
          "phoneNumber":"+16505550100"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

See the API Reference for more: https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefGetCallerId

**2) Using the Online Account Portal**

You can also change the Caller ID value in the Online Account Portal under:

`Settings` > `Outbound Calls` > `Caller ID` > `By Feature` > `Fax Number`

More is available in this Knowledgebase Article:

https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/3614

Comment: Could you please explain the way of doing it using the RIngCentral SDK. Actually what I'm using is java SDK.

Comment: Thanks for posting your Java answer. I updated the formatting. Click "edit" to see how that was done.

Comment: Thanks for making the code more readable @Grokify..

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when working with the [RingCentral Java SDK](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-java).

1. To get the sender/caller numbers list that I can use for my Fax/call

```java
RestClient rc = new RestClient(RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTID, RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTSECRET, RINGCENTRAL_SERVER);
rc.authorize(RINGCENTRAL_USERNAME, RINGCENTRAL_EXTENSION, RINGCENTRAL_PASSWORD);

GetExtensionPhoneNumbersResponse numbers = rc.restapi().account().extension().phonenumber().get();
```

2. To update the sender/caller number

```java
RestClient rc = new RestClient(RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTID, RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTSECRET, RINGCENTRAL_SERVER);
rc.authorize(RINGCENTRAL_USERNAME, RINGCENTRAL_EXTENSION, RINGCENTRAL_PASSWORD);
          
ExtensionCallerIdInfo resp = rc.restapi().account().extension().callerid().get();

for (CallerIdByFeature e : resp.byFeature) {
    if (e.callerId.phoneInfo != null) {
        e.callerId.phoneInfo.phoneNumber("**********");
    }
}
resp = rc.restapi().account().extension().callerid().put(resp);
```